# How to embed Tensorboard to Gui app in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I tried to embed TensorBoard to my GUI app with PyQt5, but I got always the same issue: the app won't display the SVG graphs it; shows only the HTML.

I want to know if there is a module or function in PyQt5 that can show SVG images in webpage using their URL(s).

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl("https://tensorboard.dev/experiment/EDZb7XgKSBKo6Gznh3i8hg/#scalars"))
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What error do you get? I can execute the code correctly: https://i.imgur.com/w5iaaSl.png

Comment: the issue is that when I execute the code the main window don't display the graphs (svg images) but it works perfectly on your python I don't understand why ( I use the last version of anaconda) , I think it's a dependency problem , do you have a solution for this issue

Comment: Recommendation: Do not use conda